# Can DTrace find non-extractable private key from Keychain on OS X?

Tags: macos, keychain, private-key, pki, dtrace

I'm trying to get a hold of a private key that [doesn't seem to be exportable from **Keychain Access.app**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/export-non-extractable-private-key-from-keychain-on-os-x) directly on OS X, probably because it was imported with the option to make it non-extractable.

What I think might work is trying to intercept the said private key when it's used by the VPN software, the web-browser or some system software for the actual PKI authentication; is there a way to do this, perhaps with DTrace?

Comment: Note that I've also started a bounty for an application of this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/export-non-extractable-private-key-from-keychain-on-os-x

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?  Can the downvoter please explain?

Comment: I've tried posting a summary of all the different methods I've tried to attack this problem, if anyone's interested: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/extract-non-extractable-private-key-from-os-x-keychain